# serial port data sending got splitted in receiver

Tags: python, pyserial

I send a data from the serial port as

```
1H|\^&|||c111^Roche^c111^2.0.0.0710^1^3334
44|||||host|TSREQ^REAL|
```

To serial port and at receiving end string got split as

```
1H|\^
```

and

```
&|||c111^Roche^c111^2.0.0.0710^1^3334
    44|||||host|TSREQ^REAL|
```

why it happened, i want to send it as a single string.

This is my code

```
 import serial
    import requests

    ser = serial.Serial(port='COM1',baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,timeout=0.5)
    concat = str()
    concat01=str()
    header = "b'\x021H|\^&||||||||||P||'\r\n"
    sample = "b'\x023Q|1|^0101645900^10^0^4^^SAMPLE^NORMAL||ALL||||||||O'\r\n"
    eol="b'\x024L|1|I'\r\n"
    patient_info = "b'\x022P|1'\r\n"

    while 1:
        z=ser.readline()
        print(z)
        print("Str Result",str(z))
        if str(z)!="b''":
            if str(z) == str(b'\x06'):
                print("verfied 06")
                concat = header + patient_info + sample + eol
                ser.write(concat.encode())
```

Comment: How do you send it? At the lowest level, your serial interface is transmitting bytes, then it is up to you (or your library) to concatenate and parse the results.

Comment: If you know how many bytes are in a packet, you should explicitly read that many bytes. If the packet size is variable, then you could prepend the packet with its size. Eg, if all packets contain <256 byes the packet size can be given by a single byte, so you read 1 byte, decode it, and then you know how many bytes to read to get the rest of the packet.

Comment: Modified my question with code

Comment: Your strings look strange "b'\x024L'" is a string with the characters b single-quote \x02 2 4 L single-quote in it.

Comment: To debug, I advise splitting into a sender and a receiver script, each using a distinct physical serial port (2 ports connected with null modem cable)